# Two javascript files, referencing a library

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple question, but I'm new to JS so I would appreciate some help.

In my index.html file I have this,

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src='jquery.base64.js'></script>
```

Within my jquery.js (I get a picture), and within my jquery.base64.js its a library I downloaded with a function that takes a binary data string and returns it as base64.

In my jquery.js I try to use this function

`$.base64.encode(text))`

but it doesnt work and it says its undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're adding code *to* the `jquery.js` that you downloaded?

Comment: You have to load the file containing the function before you can use it. Try reversing the order of the two lines.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. jquery.js is my file that I use to get an image from a link (in binary data). I'm trying to use the library I downloaded (jquery.base64.js) to turn this binary data into base64 data

Comment: Will try murgatroid thanks

Comment: It worked! Thanks lol stupid question. feel free to post so I can checkmark

Comment: Not exactly related, but may be of interest to you. Have a look at 'RequireJS'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `jquery.js` is the jQuery library that you downloaded, **please do not change it**. Create a third file, `myjs.js`, and add your `js` to it:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src='jquery.base64.js'></script>
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
```

And for you to use `jquery.base64.js` plugin, your own javascript has to be added **after** `jquery.base64.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because of the order of your files: you can't reference `jquery.base64.js` until you've loaded that. If you're working in `jquery.js` (for whatever reason), you're going to have to reverse the order of the script references:

```
<script src="jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

That will allow you to access `jquery.base64.js` from `jquery.js`.